# Unpopulated fields between two Schemas keystone.js

Tags: keystonejs

I have two models: Entity and Cabinet. Entity model can have multiple cabinets. One cabinet can have one Entity object.
In my admin UI when I create Cabinet I specify the Entity which the cabinet belongs to.

I have linked Entity to Cabinets and Cabinets to Entity like this:

models/Entity.js

```
Entity.add({ name: { type: Types.Text, initial: true, label: 'Име' }, cabinets: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'Cabinet', many: true }, })
```

models/Cabinet.js

```
Cabinet.add({ entity_id: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'Entity'}, name: { type: Types.Text, initial: true } })
```

When I save a new Cabinet and go to Entity list, I expect to see populated cabinet ( I just created )
in the column Cabinets
The column Cabinets in the Entity list view is empty.

Is this a bug in keystone.js or I have missed something?

Comment: Please mark an answer if it resolved your question.

Answer (score 1):

What you've done here is just create two different models. That being said once you create a new Cabinet you should be able to go into Entities and select that Cabinet from a search/dropdown.

Since this was asked two months ago I'm going to assume you've solved what you were looking for and moved on... but if you are still stuck could you clarify what the rest of your models have and confirm that the Cabinet that you've saved is actually generating?